# How to programmatically add a ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-progressbar

I want to put a ProgressBar ontop of a ListView programmatically, and not though the XML editor.

```
arProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an empty view above listView, then create your progress bar, and try adding it as a child of the empty view.

Comment: how can I put an empty view above the listview and add it as a child in code?

Comment: put it in XML...... create a LinearLayout above listView, give it a id, get this in JAVA code, then yourLinearLAyout.addView(yourProgressDialog);

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just hide it and show it when you need to?

Use: progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE) to show it/hide it, respectively. Set the android:visibility="gone" in the XML so it's invisible (and does not affect any of the other components' positions) until you need to show it.